# Safety of LAST_INSERTED_ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Given two tables where table A has an auto-increment unique ID which is used as the primary key in table B, if we want to write a trigger for table B to insert into table A before approaching to apply the insert command on table B, is it safe to use the LAST_INSERTED_ID function to get the auto-increment value corresponding to the inserted record in table A? By `Safety` I mean if two records are inserted in table A in an extremely short interval of time, would the the second insert (performed by the second user, in another transaction) effect the returned value by the LAST_INSERTED_ID function?

If by any chance it does, what is a safer way to obtain the auto-increment value for a specific insert command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LAST_INSERT_ID` only sees values generated within the same client session in which it is called. If the same session executes two separate `INSERT` statements, it doesn't matter how quickly the second follows the first. You get one thread per connection, one statement at a time, and `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (with no argument) will always return the *first* `AUTO_INCREMENT` value generated by the *most recent* statement, excluding the currently executing statement.

[According to the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), this remains true when using a trigger:

> Within the body of a stored routine (procedure or function) or a
>   trigger, the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` changes the same way as for
>   statements executed outside the body of these kinds of objects.

However, the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` before and after the trigger executes will be the same:

> For stored functions and triggers that change the value, the value is
>   restored when the function or trigger ends, so following statements do
>   not see a changed value.

Once you understand these rules, the following behavior will not be surprising:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a int primary key auto_increment, b int);

INSERT INTO t (b) VALUE (1);  -- (1, 1)

INSERT INTO t (b) VALUE (LAST_INSERT_ID());  -- (2, 1)

INSERT INTO t (b) VALUES
  (LAST_INSERT_ID()),  -- (3, 2) 
  (LAST_INSERT_ID()),  -- (4, 2)
  (LAST_INSERT_ID());  -- (5, 2)

INSERT INTO t (b) VALUE (LAST_INSERT_ID());  -- (6, 3)
```

Here's [the above example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f165e/1).